# Copy paste from excel to notepad++ issue

Tags: excel, notepad++

I am trying to copy data from excel and paste it in Notepad++.
When pasting in NPP, it is automatically inserting carriage return and the cursor goes on to the next line.
Is there any way to avoid this ? I want the cursor to remain at the end of the text after pasting.

Answer (score 1):

If you are copying data from a single cell, you could do one of the following:

1. Double-click on the cell and then copy its contents.
2. Select the cell you wish to copy from, and copy its contents from the Formula Bar.

If this does not solve your problem and removing the new line after every paste is annoying you, you could also consider switching to Google Sheets or Excel Online and copying data from there. They do not seem to add a new line.

Comment: The problem with trying to copy the contents of a cell or from the formula bar is that'll give you the formula rather than the value, so you might prefer to copy "4" than to copy "=2+2" to Notepad++, but cell contents or formula bar just gives you "=2+2"